# How to get the index of a letter from a list A-Z?

Tags: r, indexing, letters

I want to get the index of a particular letter, e.g.

```
>  match(LETTERS,"G")
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Gives me that the letter exists, but I want it to return 6 in this case for the 6th element of the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or `which`:

```
which(LETTERS=="G")
```

The `which` function is designed specifically for this purpose:

> Give the 'TRUE' indices of a logical
>   object, allowing for array indices.

The `which` function can also return the index for logical `TRUE` values in a matrix by setting the arr.ind argument to TRUE (this is very useful).

```
> which(matrix(LETTERS, nrow=5)=="G")
[1] 7
> which(matrix(LETTERS, nrow=5)=="G", arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   2   2
```

You may also want to read [this recent blog post from Seth Falcon](http://userprimary.net/posts/2010/03/14/r-internals-quick-tour/) where he talks about optimizing it in C.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the notice: I think you wanted

```
match("G", LETTERS)
# [1] 7
```

Benefits of this solution over `grep` or `which` is that you could use it on vector of letters:

```
match(c("S","T","A","C","K","O","V","E","R","F","L","O","W"), LETTERS)
# gives:
# [1] 19 20  1  3 11 15 22  5 18  6 12 15 23
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `grep`:

```
R> grep("G", LETTERS)
[1] 7
```